# Assign Multiselect Drop-down Options to a String Variable in PHP

Tags: php, input, drop-down-menu

I use the following code to get a list of country codes from a user and assign it to a string called 'locations.'

```
<input
    type="text" 
    class="widefat code" 
    id="edit-menu-item-visibility-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" 
    name="menu-item-visibility[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" 
    value="<?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( $item_id, 'locations', true ) ); ?>" />
    <?php echo 'Enter 2-digit country codes separated by commas, e.g. US,CA,SG' ?></br>
```

If I wanted to use the following multi-select dropdown menu instead, how could I pass the values to 'locations' as a comma separated list (string)? i.e. "US,CA,SG"

```
<select name="chzn-select" class="chzn-select" multiple="true">
    <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
    <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
</select>
```

EDIT:

Here is how the variable currently gets to the database:

```
function update_option_text( $menu_id, $menu_item_db_id, $args ) {
    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, 'locations', true );
    $new_meta_value = stripcslashes( $_POST['menu-item-visibility'][$menu_item_db_id] );

    if( '' == $new_meta_value ) {
        delete_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, 'locations', $meta_value );
    }
    elseif( $meta_value !== $new_meta_value ) {
        update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, 'locations', $new_meta_value );
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

The selected values are now getting sent to the database. But I can seem to figure out how to keep the selected values selected after saving the form.

Here's my non-working attempt to make it work by brute force:

```
<option value="AF" <?php $locations = get_post_meta( $item_id, 'locations', true); if(in_array("AF", $locations ))){echo "selected='selected'";}else{echo "";} ?> >Afghanistan</option>
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: does the user submit the form first, then the next thing would be to put those multiple selected inputs to the input box? just remember though to put `chzn-select[]` in the select name attribute. if its just a normal flat array, just use `implode`

Answer (score 3):

Just treat your `select` box as an array like :

`<select name="chzn-select[]" class="chzn-select" multiple="true">`

And your PHP code :

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST["chzn-select"])) {
  $val = implode(",",$_POST["chzn-select"]);
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok, the data gets to the database. Now, how I can keep the chosen values selected in the select box?

Comment: For that get data from database and use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on it. `explode` gives you an array. Now all you need is [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).